# How multi-scale CNN selects final output map

Tags: cnn

I read a few days ago about multi-scale CNN *(`OverFeat` method)* which you can access to presentation via this [link](http://vision.stanford.edu/teaching/cs231b_spring1415/slides/overfeat_eric.pdf). They performed CNN on different scales of an image and then combine all output maps. They said inside of that presentation:

> Classification    performed   at  6   scales  at  test time,  but only    1 scale at  run time    .

So my question is: **If we use 6 different scales of CNN architecture, then we have different convolution layers in every scale (I guess so). So how in `OverFeat`, they use 1 scale in run time? If we use a specific scale, then how can we access other feature extractors of different scales?** And I see in the article, they combine feature maps of different scales but I can't figure out how this process performed.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this as varied filter size and varied filter values. It will extract different representation (or say capture different part of the image), and then stack them to get a bigger feature vector. Then, you do the featurisation .Also, check for dilated CNNs used for NLP. They are based on somewhat similar concepts.